# Laravel: "Unknown database type _int4 requested" in migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, database-migration

I has created column `user_id` in one migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create($this->_tableName, function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        ...
```

Now I try to make this column as nullable in second migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table($this->_tableName, function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable()->change();
    });
}
```

But I obtain next message:

```
$ php artisan migrate


  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                                          
  Unknown database type _int4 requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSqlPlatform may not support it.
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know roots of this problem. But now I use:

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE " . $this->_tableName . " ALTER COLUMN user_id DROP NOT NULL");
```